# How to delete the retained resources from aws cloudformation manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I want to delete the retained resources manually after I delete the stack

I tried that

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name eksctl-simple-jwt-api-cluster --retain-resources [VPC]
```

and get that result :

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Is that enough or there is another way 
cuz I think the resources didn't delete
any help

Answer (score 0):

It's a command-line problem with `--retain-resources [VPC]`. Try changing it to:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name eksctl-simple-jwt-api-cluster --retain-resources "VPC"
```

Comment: thanks for reply Anton but not worked I deleted it manually from my AWS profile